# How to call a function of a running winform application from console application

Tags: c#, winforms, console-application

I have a windows application in running status. I have another console application which needs to interact with my winApp. I can get the running process details and set focus to the winApp from console but I am not able to call any function of winApp.

Can someone please help me out here?

Please let me know if I am not clear.

Comment: I don't think there's any way you can do that directly. I'd recommend looking into IPC (inter-process communications), for example setting up a named pipe link between the two programs.

Comment: Do you own the code for both applications?

Comment: @Sam : Yes, I have code for both on my machine only.

Comment: Do you literally mean to call the method in another application? I mean do you need to access the another process memory? Or you simply need to reuse the code in that method (executing it in your console application)?

Comment: console app listens to some other process which win app can not do due to project architecture. so console will grab the info and pass on to winform to open a form with details.

Answer (score 0):

Several possibilities:

1. You may send mouse events and key events to the windows application (very unreliable, is the right window open? and on top?, and so on)
2. You need some form of inter-process communication (IPC). (some effort)

Some possibilites for IPC:

1. shared memory
2. named pipes
3. sockets

Answer (score 0):

If the interaction is not complex, the easiest way is to post a custom message to the window.  Microsoft has reserved a range of the possible values for application-specific signals.  You use the RegisterMessage function to have a value assigned for your message(s) at runtime and for other applications to determine what the current value is.

RegisterMessage function: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644947%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

You can p/Invoke the RegisterMessage function from each application as it starts.

PostMessage function: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

You can p/Invoke the PostMessage function in your console application.

Your winforms application will then need to listen for the message, I think one place to do this is by overriding the PreFilterMessage method.

Admittedly, you don't get a lot of data that you can push along with the event.  I used this once to pass drive letters between two processes.

Answer (score 0):

Your looking at some sort of inter-process communication, and there is a number of ways to achieve this depending on the scope of what you are trying to achieve.

For example, if you need a rich interface between the applications you can host a WCF Server in the Windows Application, and connect to this as a WCF client from the console application.  This will allow you to expose methods in the app to call.

e.g:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee939340.aspx

You can also use named pipes, this gives you a simple read/write api to get information in and out of a given process, then you just handle the received information in the application and perform your functions

e.g: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546102(v=vs.110).aspx

Hope this helps.